# Do mega creeps give less experience?

Tags: dota-2, dota

I know that when the creeps are mega they only give half the normal amount of gold. Is there a difference in the amount of experience gained by killing a normal creep vs a mega creep?

Comment: Are you asking about DOTA _or_ DOTA 2? You can't ask about both :)

Comment: Considering the mechanic applies to both games, I don't think it really matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes they give less gold & experience.

> When an enemy's Barracks falls, all Lane Creeps of the associated type for that team begin to spawn as Mega Creeps. Mega Creeps are stronger versions of regular Lane Creeps **that give less Gold and Experience to the enemy when killed**. When all enemy Barracks are destroyed, Upgraded Mega Creeps begin to spawn.

**Updated of 7.07c**

Ranged creeps give 69 XP and melees give 57 XP.
Mega ranged creeps give 22 XP and melees give 25 XP.

source: https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Lane_creeps